# How to fix 'Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.'

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to 'service restart nginx' but it is not working and giving me the errors below.

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code

I have tried looking around for answers but cannot find anything.

[image]

That is what it says in the configs etc

Comment: what error? Can you please update your question with the same?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file?

Answer (score 0):

Error says that parameter "fastcgi_pass" is duplicated.

You should edit the file and fix the error in your configuration file that should be located in /etc/nginx/site-enabled/default (usually a link pointing to /etc/nginx/site-available/default). You can check configuration with command "sudo nginx -t"

After that you should start again the service using "sudo service nginx reload" or a similar command.